# Get the values from NSMutableDictionary inside NSMutableDictionary

Tags: iphone, ios5

I create two `NSMutableDictionary`: dictionary1 and dictionary2. In the first dictionary I store some array object having there keys. And in the second dictionary I store the object of first dictionary with the key like this:

```
int page = 1;
[dictionary2 setObject:dictionary1 forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",page]];
[dictionary1 removeAllObjects];
```

but at the time of retrieve of the object i do like this

```
dictionary1 = [dictionary2 valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",page]];
NSLog(@"dictionary1 %@", dictionary1);`
```

Then it gives null value. I don't know what mistake I do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you add `dictionary1` to `dictionary2`, you are removing all of the objects.

This is the same dictionary that is in dictionary2 (it does not create a copy), therefore you are removing the objects from it as well.

You need to remove the line `[dictionary1 removeAllObjects];`.

Then, since you are done with `dictionary1` at this point, you can either remove the reference to it or set to a nice new shiny dictionary which is ready to use:

```
// Remove the reference
dictionary1 = nil;

// Or, create a new, empty dictionary
dictionary1 = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
```

Comment: Thanks. But first i want removeAllObjects from dictionary1 and next time i want to add them in to dictionary1. Now what can i do.

Comment: just use:  `dictionary1 = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];` instead of `removeAllObjects` to set it to a new dictionary, or `dictionary1 = nil;` and then create the new dictionary when you are ready to use it for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Did you correctly alloc/init `dictionary1` and `dictionary2`? Make sure the dictionaries themselves are not `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   dictionary1 = [dictionary2 objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",page]];
```